# How to sort objects by date ascending order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, sorting

If I have a list of object:

```
var objectList= LIST_OF_OBJECT;
```

each **object** in the list contains three attributes: "**name**", "**date**","**gender**"

How to sort the objects in the list by "**date**" attribute ascending order?

(the "**date**" attribute contain string value like "2002-08-29 21:15:31+0500")

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method accepts a sort function, which accepts two elements as arguments, and should return:

- < 0 if the first is less than the second
- 0 if the first is equal to the second
- > 0 if the first is greater than the second.

.

```
objectList.sort(function (a, b) {
    var key1 = a.date;
    var key2 = b.date;

    if (key1 < key2) {
        return -1;
    } else if (key1 == key2) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
});
```

You're lucky that, in the date format you've provided, a date that is before another date is also `<` than the date when using string comparisons. If this wasn't the case, you'd have to convert the string to a date first:

```
objectList.sort(function (a, b) {
    var key1 = new Date(a.date);
    var key2 = new Date(b.date);

    if (key1 < key2) {
        return -1;
    } else if (key1 == key2) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: I would start by defining a new field in each value with the date already parsed for efficiency.

Comment: How about if it is not a list of objects, but a object which contain objects, and I would like to sort the objects inside a object?

Comment: @Leem: There is nothing in any standards which describes what order object members should be enumerated in (citation needed). You should convert the object to an array.

Comment: If `date` field always contains value as "2002-08-29 21:15:31+0500" and always have "+0500", then posible to compare they for sorting without parsing into `Date` object.

Answer (score 31):

If your objects have the **date** information within a *String* field:

```
yourArray.sort(function(a, b) { return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date) })
```

or, if they have it within a *Date* field:

```
yourArray.sort(function(a, b) { return a.date - b.date })
```

Comment: Congratulations for having the only sane answer here.

Comment: You don't even need `new Date` at all if they are [valid date strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript) in the same time zone.

Comment: A small modification on this great answer for anyone using typescript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40248661/6121634.

Answer (score 3):

```
yourArray.sort(function(a, b) { 
 a = new Date(a.date);
 b = new Date(b.date);
 return a >b ? -1 : a < b ? 1 : 0;
})
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try:

```
var a =[-1,0,5,4,3,2,6,1,1];
var b = totzarrange(a)
console.log(b);
```