# TypeScript sort by date not working

Tags: sorting, typescript

I have an object `TaskItemVO` with field `dueDate` which has the type `Date`:

```
export class TaskItemVO {
    
    public dueDate: Date;
}
```

I have this method which I call when I try to sort by date but it is not working:

```
public sortByDueDate(): void {
    this.myArray.sort((a: TaskItemVO, b: TaskItemVO) => {
        return a.dueDate - b.dueDate;

    });
}
```

I get this error in the return line of method:

> The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.
>
> The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.

**So what is the correct way of sorting array by date fields in TypeScript?**

Comment: As the error message shows, you need to convert the dates into numbers.

Comment: If it can be `undefined`, the class should probably note that in its signature, `public dueDate?: Date;`

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Try using the [Date.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method:

```
public sortByDueDate(): void {
    this.myArray.sort((a: TaskItemVO, b: TaskItemVO) => {
        return a.dueDate.getTime() - b.dueDate.getTime();

    });
}
```

^ Above throws error with undefined date so try below:

---

#### Edit

If you want to handle undefined:

```
private getTime(date?: Date) {
    return date != null ? date.getTime() : 0;
}


public sortByDueDate(): void {
    this.myArray.sort((a: TaskItemVO, b: TaskItemVO) => {
        return this.getTime(a.dueDate) - this.getTime(b.dueDate);
    });
}
```

Comment: This throws error when date is undefined so I'm doing a horrible hack please check update, is there any proper way?

Comment: I'm upvoting anyway but leaving accepted answer if anyone comes with proper answer, thanks for your time and answer

Comment: Check my revised answer

Answer (score 55):

As possible workaround you can use unary `+` operator here:

```
public sortByDueDate(): void {
    this.myArray.sort((a: TaskItemVO, b: TaskItemVO) => {
        return +new Date(a.dueDate) - +new Date(b.dueDate);
    });
}
```

Unary plus (+) converts an operand ( `new Date()` ) into a number.

Comment: Unary plus (+) converts an operand ( new Date() ) into a number.

https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-unary-operators/

Answer (score 9):

I believe it's better to use `valueOf`

```
public sortByDueDate(): void {
    this.myArray.sort((a: TaskItemVO, b: TaskItemVO) => {
        return a.dueDate.valueOf() - b.dueDate.valueOf();
    });
}
```

according to docs: /** Returns the stored time value in milliseconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC. */

Answer (score 8):

If you are running into issues with the accepted answer above. I got it to work by creating a new Date and passing in the date parameter.

```
  private getTime(date?: Date) {
    return date != null ? new Date(date).getTime() : 0;
  }

  public sortByStartDate(array: myobj[]): myobj[] {
    return array.sort((a: myobj, b: myobj) => {
      return this.getTime(a.startDate) - this.getTime(b.startDate);
    });
  }
```