# How to sort array by date

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is my array

```
arr=[
{
    date:'2017-06-14 14:03:49'
},
{
    date:'2017-04-20 10:25:32'
},
{
    date:'2017-06-02 15:57:16'
},
{
    date:'2017-06-02 17:52:05'
},
{
    date:'2017-06-02 21:47:13'
},
{
    date:'2017-06-14 14:01:31'
}
]
```

I need sort an array by date.

How can i do this,

Kindly advice me,

Thanks

Comment: Dunno if that's an exact duplicate. In this case, since the date strings are ISO 8601, the compare function can be simply `return a.localCompare(b)`, so no need to covert to Date at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method and within compare function parse the string and return value corresponding by getting the difference.

```js
var arr = [{
  date: '2017-06-14 14:03:49'
}, {
  date: '2017-04-20 10:25:32'
}, {
  date: '2017-06-02 15:57:16'
}, {
  date: '2017-06-02 17:52:05'
}, {
  date: '2017-06-02 21:47:13'
}, {
  date: '2017-06-14 14:01:31'
}];

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  // convert date object into number to resolve issue in typescript
  return  +new Date(a.date) - +new Date(b.date);
})

console.log(arr);
```

Refer the issue in git: [Error when doing arithmetic operations on date](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5710)

Or refer : [TypeScript sort by date not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40248643/typescript-sort-by-date-not-working)

Comment: @Pranav C Balan Thanks for ur reply.Actually i am using typescript.I am get this err left hand side an arithmetic operation must be of type any.Kindly advice me

Comment: @ANISUNDAR : updated the answer, you need to convert it to number since it's date object.... it can be done by adding `+` before the parse date

Comment: This also works when sorting SQL smalldatetime ie, `2018-07-05T20:24:00.000Z`