# Sort by date, descending in ramda js

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

https://ramdajs.com/docs/#sort

How can I use this to sort this array?

```
const prices = [
      {
        date: "2020-07-27",
        value: 157,
      },
      {
        date: "2020-07-26",
        value: 157,
      },
      {
        date: "2020-07-28",
        value: 157,
      },
    ];

const expectedOutput = [
      {
        date: "2020-07-28",
        value: 157,
      },
      {
        date: "2020-07-27",
        value: 157,
      },
      {
        date: "2020-07-26",
        value: 157,
      },
    ];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort array by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44582097/how-to-sort-array-by-date)

Comment: Note that the function passed to Ramda's `sort` function is the same as that passed to the native `Array.prototype.sort` function.

Comment: Mm. But I don't get it how to implement it with ramda

Comment: Another Ramda possibility: `sort (descend (prop ('date'))) (prices)`.  For an ascending sort, it's easier, `sort (prop ('date')) (prices)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I understand, I think you can do that with Date API like

```js
const diff = function(a, b){
 return new Date(a.date).getTime() - new Date(b.date).getTime()
}

R.sort(diff,prices);
```

If this answer is fall short of your expectation, please comment to me