# TypeScript Sorting Object by Date

Tags: typescript

I have this little code I borrowed from another question for sorting objects in an array by date. However, I can't figure out how to port this to TypeScript.

```
this.filteredTxs.sort(function(a,b): any{
        return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
});
```

TS Error:

> ERROR in /transactions-view.component.ts(72,16): error TS2362: The
>   left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any',
>   'number' or an enum type.
>
> /transactions-view.component.ts(72,35): error TS2363: The right-hand
>   side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an
>   enum type.

Comment: What is unclear from the error message? You're subtracting *dates*, which will cause implicit type coercion, which TypeScript avoids.

Comment: The actual duplicate is [TypeScript sort by date not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40248643/215552)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Reason**

The type signature for [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is:

```
sort(compareFn?: (a: T, b: T) => number): this;
```

which means the `compareFn` should return a `number`. In your case, you're trying to subtract an object from another object which doesn't make much sense. It works only because JavaScript implicitly coerces their type for you.

**Solution 1**

> Judging by your question, I assume `filteredTxs` are objects that
>   include a `date` property of type `Date`.

Cast your `Date` objects to a number explicitly:

```
this.filteredTxs.sort(function(a,b): any{
        return (b.date.getTime() - a.date.getTime());
});
```

**Solution 2**

Use implicit casting to compare dates, but only for comparison purposes, not for subtraction.

```
this.filteredTxs.sort(function(a,b): any {
  .sort((a, b) => {
    if (left.date === right.date) {
      return 0;
    }

    return (left.date > right.date)
      ? 1
      : -1
});
```

Comment: Solution 1 is just as incorrect as the OP's code, it's not clear what you're trying to achieve by assuming `a.date` and `b.date` are `Date` objects but then creating new `Date` objects...? Also, *"...which means the `compareFn` should return a `number`."* The OP's code **does** return a number. the problem is with the `-` operator, not the `sort` method callback.

Comment: Solution 1 worked for me. The `date` properties _are_ `date` objects. However, why is that I have to create a `new Date()` to access `getTime()` function on them? Is that because of the prototype?

Comment: Not at all, it was just a leftover from me experimenting in DevTools. I cleaned up my answer. I apologize for creating confusion.

Answer (score 26):

Rather than relying on coercing `Date` objects to their underlying milliseconds-since-The-Epoch number values, you want to get the milliseconds-since-The-Epoch value directly and use that in the `-` expression.

You haven't told us what `a.date` and `b.date` are, but we can infer that they're either strings, numbers, or (at a stretch) `Date` instances.

### Assuming `a.date` and `b.date` are *strings*

If `a.date` and `b.date` are strings, you can use [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) to parse the strings with the same rules as `new Date` and get the milliseconds-since-The-Epoch value directly:

```
return Date.parse(b.date) - Date.parse(a.date);
```

Note that both that and the original code in your question assume that `a.date` and `b.date` are really in an [appropriate format](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format) to be parsed by the `Date` object.

### Assuming `a.date` and `b.date` are numbers

If `a.date` and `b.date` are *already* milliseconds-since-The-Epoch values, use them directly:

```
return b.date - a.date;
```

### Assuming `a.date` and `b.date` are `Date` instances

If `a.date` and `b.date` are `Date` instances, use `getTime` to get their underlying milliseconds-since-The-Epoch value:

```
return b.date.getTime() - a.date.getTime();
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, a.date and b.date are date object, but using `b/a.date.getTime()` was giving me an error : `a.date.getTime() is not a function`. But using `new Date(a.date).getTime()` works just fine. Wondering if the date objects are not really date object because I read them back from local storage? Not sure.

Comment: @Aragorn - If you're getting that error, they aren't `Date` objects. *"Wondering if the date objects are not really date object because I read them back from local storage?"* Yes. Web storage only stores **strings**.

Comment: Hey, I tried this on mine but it didn't work.. ```ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getTime'```

Comment: I'm trying to sort my objects by their Date field and tried your #3 solution. They are Date objects in my backend as well as my front-end

Comment: Nvm, I did the ```new Date(a.date).getTime()``` and it worked!

Comment: @Donnygroezinger - What was the code that gave you the `TypeError` above? Because if it was `a.date.getTime()`, then your code that seems to work (`new Date(a.date).getTime()`) doesn't work (or works by coincidence). `new Date(null)` gives you Jan 1st 1970 at midnight GMT. It sounds like you have `null`s for `a.date` in at least some of your array elements.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just as confused. I have an actual date in my backend shown here: ```date:2021-10-10T05:00:00.000+00:00```. I store it as a Date type in my ```.ts``` file as well. I saw that I messed it up in my backend when I was getting my first error, then when I fixed that and tried it again, I was getting the same error as the other person.. I fixed it with the New Date. Not sure why.